# How do you track in realtime the costs of google cloud VM instances

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I just signed up for google cloud and I would like to track my costs in real time or at least by the hour.

From the documentation costs are incurred in 10-minute bundles but I cannot view costs incurred in my Billings area.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just spent way to much time with support to find this:

- goto Reports tab in GCE
- click Group by SKU
- uncheck Credits > Discounts, One time credits
- click Daily and change to Daily Cumulative
- exhale

There is also a breakdown of charges so far in the each month under Transactions tab that is less useful.

[image]

Comment: Is GCP on purpose trying to be like this... So far all I have is bad things to say about it... It's so convoluted, GPU quotas are being rejected and finding help is a B-word.

Comment: This answer makes sense, this information is not available on anywhere in GC Documentation.